# UITapGestureRecognizer & UIDataDetectorTypes working simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UITapGestureRecognizer like this:

```
var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissIfKeyboardIsShowing")
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

// This part is because I have other gestures
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

And a UITextView like this:

```
    var aTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height))
    aTextView.font = UIFont(name:ThemeFontName, size: fontSize)
    aTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    aTextView.textColor = ThemeNicknameColor
    aTextView.clipsToBounds = true
    aTextView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    aTextView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    aTextView.editable = false
    aTextView.scrollEnabled = false

    aTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.Link // -- !!!!!!!!!!!!!

    view.addSubview(aTextView)
```

All looks good, except when I click on the link while my 'tap' is disabled I have no problem and the link sends me to Safari as expected.

When I click on the link while my 'tap' is enabled, only the 'tap' is working and the link doesn't work anymore.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try setting the `cancelsTouchesInView` property of your `TapGestureRecognizer` to `false`.

Comment: tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
wrote this and didnt work